# Deploying AppInvite in Android App using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am deploying the AppInvite by Firebase. Everything is working fine except the way it sends the link and all.

I saw in other apps like Phonepe & Tez the screen is quite different. In their app, there is picker dialog comes from the bottom rather than the whole screen as in Firebase AppInvite.

[image: Like this. I don't want this to appear]

I don't want the above image just a dialog and the user goes directly to the WhatsApp or any other app.

Since Tez is a product of Google they must be using the Firebase App invite but their flow is quite different from the one. And it doesn't see any way to customize the screen since it doesn't go with my app's UI.